# Sorting portion of a python list based on attribute of a class

Tags: python

Another potentially simple question from myself.

I have defined a class like so:

```
class NSObjects:
    def __init__(self, shape, position, shading):
        self.shape = shape
        self.position = position
        self.shading = shading

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self)
```

The attributes above are simply integers. My goal is to sort certain parts of an array called "Obj1" on the shape attribute.

I have tried to accomplish this below and print out the results

```
print(repr(obj1))
shapesortedobj1[0:2] = sorted(obj1[0:2], key = lambda NSObjects: NSObjects.shape)
shapesortedobj1[3:5] = sorted(obj1[3:5], key = lambda NSObjects: NSObjects.shape)
shapesortedobj1[6:8] = sorted(obj1[6:8], key = lambda NSObjects: NSObjects.shape)

print(repr(shapesortedobj1))
```

But the output I am getting is this:

```
[1 1 1, 2 2 2, 0 0 0, 1 1 1, 2 2 2, 0 0 0, 2 2 2, 0 0 0, 1 1 1] --> Before
[1 1 1, 2 2 2, 1 1 1, 2 2 2, 0 0 0, 2 2 2] --> After
```

Ideally I would have the same number of list elements, and everything should be sorted on the first number (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is hard to understand. What are the elements of obj1? Are they all NSObjects instances? (And why have you also used the name NSObjects as the parameter to the lambda? That's very confusing.)

Comment: Sorry - obj1 is a list composed of NSObject Objects which I am hoping are being read as a series of integers. 

On the question of NSObjects, I have seen the convention for lambda to use either 'x' or the actual class you are referring to. Didn't know which one the best to use was but I am guessing it is x now!

Comment: Also slicing is not inclusive of the stop element, so you will likely need to increase your stops by one, e.g. `obj1[0:3]`, `obj1[3,6]` etc.

Comment: Thank you AChampion! A simple oversight. I really need to get better at spotting these novice errors. Thanks

Comment: Does replacing it with `shapesortedobj1[0:3] = sorted(obj1[0:3], key=lambda x: x.shape)`, etc. fix your issue? BTW there are better ways to chunk you list into groups of 3 - there are plenty of examples on SO (and a recipe `grouper()` in `itertools`).

Comment: Yep - that does the think. I will have a look at grouper and itertools - are these libraries that you import or already exist in python?

Comment: [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#module-itertools)  needs to be imported, [grouper()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) uses a method from `itertools`